# Extruding mesh along a path with taper

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude, path

So after working on this helmet for weeks now, I've hit a snag.
I'm trying to extrude part of the mesh along a curve to create the horns.
When I try either nothing happens or it just stretches off into the distance.

I've tried doing this along a curve and path with the same results.

I'm fairly new to blender so I'm sure someone will be facepalming at my efforts.

Help would be appreciated.
[image: Attemt to follow curve]

Comment: Hello, first your topology is not correct, it is made of a lot of triangles, try to use quads and as few as possible, make it as simple as possible. Also you're talking about extruding along a path, but if the horns are part of the helmet you can't do such an operation as it will affect the whole object. What you could do is create another object, the horn, use array along curve if you like this method, then join the result with the helmet. But you should find a simpler method. Perhpas share an image reference of the helmet...

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have tried changing it to quads with the same effect. I would like to share an image if what I'm trying to do but I don't quite know how.